# change css hover class to jquery click

Tags: jquery, function, css, click, hover

I'm creating a menue for a site. I'm trying to change a hover to click effect on links.

A menu-item has to change when I hover over the sub-menu.

This is the code

```
<li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#">item 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">subitem 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">subitem 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">subitem 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">subitem 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#">item 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">subitem 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">subitem 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">subitem 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">subitem 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

and css

```
.nav>li>a {
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            width: 150px;
            margin-left: -5px;
            padding: 10px 10px 10px 15px;
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            font-weight: 900;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #383838;
}
.nav>li>a:hover, .nav>li:hover>a {
            color: white;
            width: 169px;
            height: 4px;
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #A30C0C, #C42D2D);
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #A30C0C, C42D2D);
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #A30C0C, C42D2D);
            background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #A30C0C, C42D2D);
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff',                         endColorstr='#f3f3f3',GradientType=0);
}
```

please, help me

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Do you want to change main menu item on hover of sub-item?

Comment: I've recently implemented a drop down menu on my website at the bottom of the page to expand when the mouse hovers over it... This is the code and it all works great. But I'm curious about how I would go about changing this to open and close on a click rather than the mouse hovering over it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need something like this: [SAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RZV4a/)

```
$(".dropdown ul").hide();
$(".dropdown ul li").click(function(){
     $(this).parent().prev('a').html($(this).text());
});
$(".dropdown").hover(function(){
     $(this).find('ul').stop(true,true).slideDown('normal');
      }, function(){
     $(this).find('ul').stop(true,true).slideUp('normal');
});
```